# HTTP status for unrespected route call order

Tags: rest, http

I am currently implementing a small client-server application in which the user can load different files. My application requires the files to be loaded in a certain order. File loading is done via interface buttons that, when clicked, trigger the sending of a GET request to the server on a certain route.

The buttons are disabled when the file loading requires the loading of other files. I guess I should still send an error message with a certain status if a route is called before the ones it depends on. I've thought of using the 403 status code to indicate that the access to the route is forbidden but this prohibition is only temporary and is not linked to the possession of certain access rights. Any idea of a better HTTP status ?

Comment: I usually use https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html - maybe 409 Conflict, although in this case it's incompatible with not having had the previous request? Failing that, 422 Unprocessable Entity.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 409 is not really about multiple requests, it's about the state of resources. An earlier request changes the state which makes the new request possible, so 409 definitely works here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `412 PRECONDITION FAILED`

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 412 Precondition Failed client
>   error response code indicates that access to the target resource has
>   been denied. This happens with conditional requests on methods other
>   than GET or HEAD when the condition defined by the If-Unmodified-Since
>   or If-None-Match headers is not fulfilled. In that case, the request,
>   usually an upload or a modification of a resource, cannot be made and
>   this error response is sent back.

Or `503 Service Unavailable`

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have:

- Multiple resources
- HTTP requests to some resources have a dependency on the state of other resources.

In other words: if resource A is not in the correct state, a HTTP request to resource  B is not allowed.

The correct HTTP status code for this is `409 Conflict`.